# Google Cloud Messaging and MySQL database

Tags: java, php, android, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-messaging

I want to use Google Cloud Messaging for my app for both upstream and downstream use, using xmpp. However I am wondering how I can select and input data to and from my MySQL database to be sent over the GCM network.

Can I use PHP with GCM or do I have to use Java or Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCM is used for sending messages FROM server TO your android application. Also a GCM message can only carry a maximum of 4KB Only.
So in my opinion, send data to your MySQL db directly from the app (If you want to make this asynchronous, look into Android Sync Adapter); and for sending data from server to your application asynchronously, send a ping to your app using GCM (it can be any short message), so your app can undergo a normal http request-response procedure to get the data from MySQL.

For more information of Sync Adapters: http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html

And for a tutorial on a simple GCM using PHP: http://www.programming-techniques.com/2014/01/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-in-android.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I use volley anyway to input and select data from my database, but I want to use gcm mainly for notifications. The problem is I want to be able to send the notification from a php script for example when a user enters a comment and the comment is added to the database via php the php script then needs to send the gcm to other users informing them of the comment. So I am trying to work out how to call the gcm from php that way.

Answer (score 0):

There are XMPP libraries for PHP. See https://code.google.com/p/xmpphp/ for example. 
So, PHP is possible, however i would really like to hear what is a recommended approach, as im going to implement it too.